# What is the proper way to generate, store, and configure an SSH public/private key pair for git repository usage on Assembla?

Tags: git, ssh, assembla

I initialized a local git repository on my desktop running Linux Mint 13.  To push to the repository on Assembla I need to have an ssh key.

I first try to generate a new key as such in the terminal:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

The response is:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/ryan/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

I tried "gitrep". Then I get the following message.

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again:
```

I left them blank because they are optional as far as I know, but just for the record, adding a passphrase does not change the result.  Then...

```
Your identification has been saved in gitrep.
Your public key has been saved in gitrep.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
da:80:b9:c5:cd:50:9c:1c:49:7f:b7:db:71:92:1e:6a ryan@ryan-MS-7309
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|       +++       |
|       .=.       |
|      .   . . .  |
|     + +   . . o |
|    o + S     =..|
|     o +     o =o|
|    . . .   E o .|
|           .     |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Now, I navigate to home/ryan/.ssh/id_rsa the folder is empty, but here's the strange thing.  If I redo the above process again using the same file name for the key it adds in:

```
gitrep already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)?
```

I do not understand what is going on.

The next part of my question is what I am supposed to do with this generated file.  Do I leave it where it is?  Do I copy information out of it to some place on Assembla.

I apologize in advance if I have asked the question in such a way as to not follow the actual process as I am not extremely familiar with the subject.

Comment: So, for future searchers: it turns out the specific problem I had here was not understanding that "ssh-keygen -t rsa" saved the generated files to the current directory in the terminal, and not the typical default directory displayed after the command is entered.  If I typed the command from /home/ryan, then they would be in /home/ryan.  Typed the command from /home/ryan/.ssh/id_rsa, then it would be there and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are just entering `gitrep`, it's just saving it in your current directory (which is apparently your home directory, judging from your example above).

Check and see if `~/gitrep` and `~/gitrep.pub` exist. You'll need to copy the contents of the `gitrep.pub` file to the destination when it asks you for your public key.

Comment: I see what it did.  It saved it to the current directory I was at in the terminal, which was /opt/lampp/.  Should it generate two files like that?  Does it matter where I keep them, or does my system store this key on its own somewhere when I generate it?

Comment: @Unipartisandev yes it should generate two files. One is your public key that you distribute to anyone you want to communicate over SSH with (it will be the `*.pub` file, "pub" for "public" key. The other one is your private key file, and you should ***not*** share that with ***anyone***, it's like your password for logging into places that you've given your public key to.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster states (emphasis mine):

> Then I get the following message.
>
> > ```
> > Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):  
> > Enter same passphrase again:
> > ```
>
> I left them blank because they are optional as far as I know, but just for the record, ***adding a passphrase does not change the result***.

I beg to differ.  ***Adding a passphrase encrypts your private key***, so that if someone manages to steal your private key file from your computer, they still can't read and use it without the passphrase that decrypts it.

You are right that adding a passphrase it *optional*, but it's still **highly recommended**.

To illustrate the difference, let's pretend that your ***un-encrypted*** private key file  contents (without a passphrase) look like this (example adapted from [Improving the security of your SSH private key files](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2013/05/24/improving-security-of-ssh-private-keys.html#the_unencrypted_private_key_format))

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEArCQG213utzqE5YVjTVF5exGRCkE9OuM7LCp/FOuPdoHrFUXk
y2MQcwf29J3A4i8zxpES9RdSEU6iIEsow98wIi0x1/Lnfx6jG5Y0/iQsG1NRlNCC
aydGvGaC+PwwWiwYRc7PtBgV4KOAVXMZdMB5nFRaekQ1ksdH/360KCGgljPtzTNl
09e97QBwHFIZ3ea5Eih/HireTrRSnvF+ywmwuxX4ubDr0ZeSceuF2S5WLXH2+TV0
    ... etc ... lots of base64 blah blah ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This value stored in your private key can be used to impersonate yourself to any 2nd party who you've given your public key to (in this case Assembla). It's basically as if a hacker had stolen the password to your account and used it to login as you...in the SSH world, this is the equivalent to that.

Now, let's hypothetically say that if you had encrypted the same private key above with a passphrase, then the file contents would look like this (again adapted from [Improving the security of your SSH private key files](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2013/05/24/improving-security-of-ssh-private-keys.html#passphraseprotected_keys)):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,D54228DB5838E32589695E83A22595C7

3+Mz0A4wqbMuyzrvBIHx1HNc2ZUZU2cPPRagDc3M+rv+XnGJ6PpThbOeMawz4Cbu
lQX/Ahbx+UadJZOFrTx8aEWyZoI0ltBh9O5+ODov+vc25Hia3jtayE51McVWwSXg
wYeg2L6U7iZBk78yg+sIKFVijxiWnpA7W2dj2B9QV0X3ILQPxbU/cRAVTd7AVrKT
    ... etc ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Do you see how the contents look different from the un-encrypted file?  This makes your private key useless to anyone who happens to steal it, unless they also happen to have the passphrase that decrypts it back to its unencrypted form.

This is the reason that GitHub gives for [Why you need a passphrase for your private SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#why-do-i-need-a-passphrase):

> Passwords aren't very secure, you already know this. If you use one that's easy to remember, it's easier to guess or brute-force. If you use one that's random, it's hard to remember and thus you're more inclined to write the password down. Both of these are Very Bad Things™. This is why you're using ssh keys.
>
> But using a key without a passphrase is basically the same as writing down that random password in a file on your computer. Anyone who gains access to your drive has gained access to every system you use that key with. This is also a Very Bad Thing™. The solution is obvious, add a passphrase.

In the same help article, they explain [how to use the *nix utility `ssh-agent` to automatically store your passphrase during a terminal session](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#but-i-dont-want-to-enter-a-long-passphrase-every-time-i-use-the-key) so that you don't have to keep entering it every time you use your private key to make an SSH request.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanations!  On a side note, when I said that leaving the password out did not matter I simply meant it did not affect my ability to locate the .pub file ;)  Now that I know the details I'll be sure to use one.

Answer (score 1):

When you are at this step:

"Enter file in which to save the key (/home/ryan/.ssh/id_rsa):"

You should just accept the default and save your key in your home directory (/home/ryan) in the .ssh folder as id_rsa.  Then you public key will be located at /home/ryan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <--- this key is the one you want to upload to your Assembla account.

Now that you have your ssh key stored in the default location, you will not have to do anything else to utilize it.

With it uploaded to your Assembla account, you will be able to then git clone:

git clone git@git.assembla.com:repo_name

When you answer "gitrep", you are saving the key to this file, in your current directory, I assume home dir (/home/ryan).

Comment: Turns out I was actually in /opt/lampp at the time because I'm trying to push the root of my development (/opt/lampp) to the origin.  So you're saying that once I generate the ssh key that it doesn't really matter where I keep the file on the local drive?

Comment: well it does not really matter if you setup your .ssh/config in your home directory - but I would use the default location so that you do not have to do this, (/home/ryan/.ssh/id_rsa) - it will remove any confusion later.